# Angular 5: Observable from Subject not assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, subject

I have a service.ts file passing a Observables in between my Angular Components and I have the result of a click event on one Component being passed to the component below.

My problem is that I can `console.log` the object that I *want* to store in my `selectedContact` variable (see below), but when I attempt to assign the `subscribe()` response to my `selectedContact` variable and then bind it to my HTML, it just shows as `[object Object].

Here's my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-details',
  templateUrl: './contact-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-details.component.scss']
})
export class ContactDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedContact: any[] = [];

  error: string;

  constructor(private _apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() { this.showContact() }

  showContact() {
  this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
    data => this.selectedContact = data)
  }
}
```

When I run this:

```
  showContact() {
  this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data))
  }
```

I get the *correct* Object logging to the console (the click event from the other component).

But when I run this:

```
  showContact() {
  this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
    data => this.selectedContact = data)
  }
```

I get `[Object Object]`

What am I missing? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in html, you bind `this.selectedContact` to some html component. But since `this.selectedContact` is an object, you have to bind to its property like so: `{{selectedContact.proppertyName }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you did this:

```
showContact() {
  this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
  data => this.selectedContact = JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

...you'd see your object, but it's not going to be formatted that well. You'll have to do more work to get well-formatted output.